# When does a Scheduled Reminder send

Tags: scheduled-reminders

If I create a Scheduled Reminder based on an Activity with a specific status and set it to trigger 0 hours after Activity Date Time will it fire immediately when the activity is created or when the next Scheduled Reminder cron job runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reminder will be sent when the next background Scheduled Reminder task is executed.  I have the exact same situation and the reminder was sent by the Scheduled Reminder task 9 minutes later than the trigger because there was a large number of emails being sent. So you can't bank on it being sent immediately.

Comment: That's how I was hoping it would work. Thanks!