# When are scheduled reminders sent?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

We are in the process of setting up some renewal reminders for lapsed members. The reminder is set to be sent 7 days after the membership end date.

What I wanted to check is whether this reminder will be sent to members whose end date is *exactly* 7 days before or if it will be sent to members whose end date is 7 days or more? i.e. will it be sent to members that expired 8 days ago, 14 days ago, 2 years ago etc?

I presume that it is an exact match. Could someone confirm this (and ideally point to where this is in the code)?

What I don't want to do is send the reminder to every former member including those that expired years ago.

Comment: See also this related (but different) question https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16299/when-does-a-scheduled-reminder-send

Comment: From my testing it does indeed appear to be an exact match so emails are only sent to members whose expiry date is exactly 7 days before. Would be great if someone could point to the code that implements this.

Comment: Whatever it does now, it might change! See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/365 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18298 (currently not merged)

Comment: Thanks @Aidan, that's helpful. It is a different use case (events rather than memberships) but it does point me to the relevant parts of the code and some of the complexities!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule reminders configured for all the available entities except for participant will send reminder on exact same day match in your case it would be on 7th day after expiry date.

For events participant its different, in current version of civi if you have configured send reminder for event start date after 7 days than it will send reminder for all the participant whose event start date is past 7 days